# Embedding a slickgrid graph to fill the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, slickgrid

I was wondering if there is any CSS/HTML/JavaScript magic to do what I want here. Right now, the code for an application has some hard-coded dimensions, 1100x600, but I wanted to have the WIDTH match up with the browser window's width instead.

```
<DIV id="dynamic1" style="width:1100px;height:600px;">
<script> ... java script slickgrid graph ... </script>
</DIV>
```

I was thinking of including a block of CSS like so:

```
#dynamic1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

But unfortunately, that makes the graph fill the whole screen. What I really want is for the graph to be embedded in a specific location on the page; I don't want it taking up the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your CSS a little bit, I hope this is what you need:

```
#dynamic1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:600px;
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `style="width:1100px;height:600px;"` part of your div.